# Ick! 0xa0a0a0a in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jar, zip, unzip

I am trying to unzip archive using `fastjar`

But when I run `jar xvf protoc-3.19.1-linux-s390_64.zip`
I receive strange error `Ick! 0xa0a0a0a`
What does it mean and how could I solve this?

I run Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Do you have any reason not to use unzip?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I had a wrong link to `zip` archive, thus I have been getting strange errors in both `unzip` and `jar xvf`. Thank you for the answer!